# PHPStorm sintax highlight for .html.twig

Tags: phpstorm

I noticed that phpstorm doesn't consider *myfile.html.twig* file as a twig file type.
If i use *myfile.js.twig*, it's considered a twig file.
Do you know why ? Is there a solution ?

Comment: Something must be wrong with your file types associations. What file type is used instead? Please share a screenshot with a file icon

Comment: It's considered php i think. [Here is a screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/tYKPMNT/Cattura.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check name patterns registered for **PHP** file type in **Settings | Editor | File Types** - do you have patterns like `.html.twig` there?

[image]

if yes, removing them from the list would likely help

Comment: No. I've as your + [test, \*.ht\*]. But removing *.ht* made it work. Wonder why it was there. Thanks. ;)